# Javascript Heap Out of memory error when inserting documents into MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv, mongoose

I am currently doing a project where my Database Management System is MongoDB. I am using mongoose as the Object Data Modelling. Here, I have to read a **.csv** file that contains more than 3 million records. I am using npm module CSV-parser [https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser][1] to read all the records as JSON objects into an array as their documentation said.

```
const results = [];
fs.createReadStream('myFile.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (data) => {
    if (data.id !== '48') { // I don't want to include this particular document/json object
      results.push(data);
    }
  })
```

The results array has all the records except the one that I don't want to include. Now, I want to insert these JSON objects into my **photos** collection in MongoDB. I first tried to insert the results array into the **photos** collection like this.

```
fs.createReadStream('myFile.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (data) => {
    if (data.id !== '48') {
      results.push(data);
    }
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    <PhotoModelName>.insertMany(results, (err, data) => {
       if (err) {
             console.log(err);
         } else {
           console.log('End successfully');
       }      
})
    
  });
```

Which did not work, I got **Heap Out of Memory** error. Then, instead of inserting all those documents together, I tried to take 20 documents per batch and insert them into the collection like this.

```
fs.createReadStream('myFile.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (data) => {
    if (data.id !== '48') {
      results.push(data);
    }
  })
  .on('end', () => {
     let i = 0;
     let j = 20;
     while (j < results.length) {
       (async () => {
         await <PhotoModelName>.insertMany(results.slice(i, j + 1));
       })();
       i = j + 1;
       j += 20;
     }
    console.log('End successfully');
  });
```

Again, I am getting the same **Out of memory error**. Can someone kindly help how to insert the documents/JSON objects into the collection? What is the best way to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.